# how to make a div return to starting point when the div slides to end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make am image scroll that uses control button and also slides automatically, my problem now is I need to know how to return the div to starting point when the div hit end on left side or on right side, what I could get so far is to know when the div hit an end but don't know how to return it to starting point in case of automatic sliding.

```
    var n = 3; //total number of slides to be display at once
var totalDeal = 9; //total deals to be display
var sliderTotalWidth = 100; //in percentage append % later
var z = (100 / totalDeal) + '%'; //ddslides width
var x = totalDeal / n;
var counter = 1;
$(".dialyDealSlider").css('width', x + '00%');
//$(".ddslides").css('width', ddslidesWidth);
fillDailyDeal(totalDeal, z);

function fillDailyDeal(totalDeal, z) {
  var imgUrl = '{$img}';
  var ext = '.jpg';
  var width = "width:" + z
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalDeal; i++) {
    var myDiv = $(
      "<div class='ddslides' style='" + width + "' >" +
      '<div class="dddesc">' +
      '<div class="ddtitle">' +
      '<a href="#">The is the title of the item it\'s a long title</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      "<div class='ddprice'>$"+i+"00</div>" +
      '<button class="ddview" title="View Item">view item</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="ddimg">' +

      '</div>' +
      '<div class="vDivider"></div>' +
      '<div class="ddSaleBadge">sold 44%</div>' +
      '</div>');
    $("#dialyDealSlider").append(myDiv);
  }
}

$("#prev, #next").click(function() {

  if (this.id == "next") {
    counter++;
  } else {
    counter--;
  }
  //console.log(counter);
  if (counter == x) {
    alert('rigth end');
    //$("#dialyDealSlider").css('left', '0px'); 
  }

  if (counter == 1) {
    alert('left end');
  }

  var ddslidesWidth = $(".ddslides").width();

  var dir = this.id == "next" ? '-=' : '+=';
  var width = ddslidesWidth * n;

  //alert(leftpos);
  $("#dialyDealSlider").animate({
    left: dir + width
  }, 800);

});
```

my code is here JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/sammyzeal/LqpL1n2g/

As we can see in the above fiddle, when we slide the div and the price is between `$700` and `$900` we hit an end then there's an alert, on this point if a user keeps on clicking this next button how do I scroll to the starting point which is between price $100 and $300, I hope my question is cleared and thanks in advance for any help

Comment: that is not scroll that is slide

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam  thanks for that correction, i will correct that but by the way can you help with the solution

Comment: you need to keep a track of what is the current index of the slides so that you can compare it with max number of slides when reaching the last item, or before sliding check if there are next 3 slides, you should slide back to the first if there arent any more, and same goes for the slide left when you reach the first slide go to the last or just stop sliding left if there are no more slides on the left. you can start working on it i am in office at the moment so wont be able to add code here, will reply once i reach home you can update your script till then

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam thanks am right on that

Comment: added an answer see if it helps i saw your update and continued the code from there.

Comment: @ Muhammad Omer Aslam thanks so much for your help, what i could com up with so far is try to hide the left and right button to prevent further sliding when the div slide to end and vise versa, as shown in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sammyzeal/LqpL1n2g/ but that wasn't actually what i wanted, i wanted to keep sliding and returning to the start point, i try to set the left property of the containing element to 0 so it can reset to the startt but that doesn't seen to work for me

Comment: i added the answer below does not it work the same way as you want it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw that you updated the code as i said , good work. So i wont hesitate to help now, you should make a separate `slideNow()` function that slides `next` or `previous` and you should increment/decrement the `counter` after checking the current or previous slides, if it is the last slide create a function separate to `goToStart()` to move to the first slide and if it is th first slide just `return` from there and do nothing, you can use the following script and test it with various combinations like, first going to the last slide by clicking and then on the last slide click next and see if it goes to the first on and then try clicking left from the first slide and verify if it goes left or stays still.

See a demo below

```js
var n = 3; //total number of slides to be display at once
var totalDeal = 9; //total deals to be display
var sliderTotalWidth = 100; //in percentage append % later
var z = (100 / totalDeal) + '%'; //ddslides width
var x = totalDeal / n;
var counter = 1;
$(".dialyDealSlider").css('width', x + '00%');
//$(".ddslides").css('width', ddslidesWidth);
fillDailyDeal(totalDeal, z);

function fillDailyDeal(totalDeal, z) {
  var imgUrl = '{$img}';
  var ext = '.jpg';
  var width = "width:" + z
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalDeal; i++) {
    var myDiv = $(
      "<div class='ddslides' style='" + width + "' >" +
      '<div class="dddesc">' +
      '<div class="ddtitle">' +
      '<a href="#">The is the title of the item it\'s a long title</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      "<div class='ddprice'>$" + i + "00</div>" +
      '<button class="ddview" title="View Item">view item</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="ddimg">' +

      '</div>' +
      '<div class="vDivider"></div>' +
      '<div class="ddSaleBadge">sold 44%</div>' +
      '</div>');
    $("#dialyDealSlider").append(myDiv);
  }
}

$("#prev, #next").click(function() {
  var target = this.id;

  //console.log(counter);
  if (counter == x && target == "next") {
    counter = 1;
    goToStart();
    return;
  }

  if (counter == 1 && target == "prev") {
    return;
  }

  if (target == "next") {
    counter++;
  } else {
    counter--;
  }

  //slide the slides
  slideNow(target, n);
});

function goToStart() {
  $("#dialyDealSlider").animate({
    left: 0
  }, 800);
}

function slideNow(target, n) {
  var ddslidesWidth = $(".ddslides").width();

  var dir = target == "next" ? '-=' : '+=';
  var width = ddslidesWidth * n;

  //alert(leftpos);
  $("#dialyDealSlider").animate({
    left: dir + width
  }, 800);
}
```

```css
.dailyDeal {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.dialyDealBox {
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dialyDealSlider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.ddslides {
  height: 150px;
  width: 2%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .ddslides {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:320px) {
  .ddslides {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

.ddimg {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 32%;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.ddimg>a>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dddesc {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 0 10px 0 15px;
}

.ddSaleBadge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 37px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 5px 2px 4px 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("/trobay/img/icon/label.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.ddtitle {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ddtitle>a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ddtitle>a:hover {
  color: #e4393c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ddprice {
  color: #e4393c;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ddview {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e4393c;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ddslider-prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
  display: block;
}

.ddslider-next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
  display: block;
}

.vDivider {
  height: 130px;
  border-right: 1px dotted #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  ;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="dailyDeal col-md-12">

    <div class="dialyDealBox col-xs-10" id="dialyDealBox">
      <div class="dialyDealSlider" id="dialyDealSlider">


      </div>
      <div class="ddslider-prev" id="prev">&#10094;</div>
      <div class="ddslider-next" id="next">&#10095;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you see my answer it returns to the first slide after you click next on reaching the last slide, i hope that is what you intended to do @sam

Comment: thanks alot i will accept your answer and i will continue from there

Comment: you are welcome ,is there still something left you wanted to implement ? @sam

Comment: Muhammad Omer Aslam  yes i guess it a matter of adding effects and animation but am not sure, just wanted to achieve kind of slide effect used widely in this site  https://www.jd.com/ Note: not the main slide with navigation dots

Comment: so you want the dots to be indicating the slides and on hover, it should show the desired slide if i understand correctly? or you want the slides to keep moving by themselves

Comment: No i don't want to include dot, just below the slides that have dot is another slide without dot, that what am trying to actualize, you've helped a lot with that but the actual effect am required to do is when a user click on either the left or the right arrow all the content of the divs keep sliding in the same direction even while it hit an end it will slide in the first div but still in the same direction, i think to actualize this i need to make changes to my html and css i need to make many div separately and hide all of them only displaying the  current on